# Do EM waves transmit spin polarization?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, condensed-matter, quantum-electrodynamics, quantum-spin

Suppose you have a normal dipole antennae (transmitter and receiver) . Spin polarized current (as opposed to normal current) is sent into the transmitter, it emits an EM wave and the Receiver receives it. Will the charge carriers in the receiver become spin polarized as well? In other words, will the spin polarization of the transmitter current have some effect on the receiver, like for example imposing the spin polarization on the receiver carriers by means of making EM radiation circularly polarized?

I am aware that this effect is possible using certain semiconductors. But I am talking about a normal metal chunk used as the antennae. I am wondering whether the spin polarization of the transmitter current will have any effect on the receiver on a deeper level: using principles of Quantum Field Theory and Quantum Electrodynamics? (I don't know anything about QFT and QED btw)

Comment: If the receiver is made of a non-ferromagnetic conductor, it might not support a spin-polarized current even if the EM radiation does carry angular momentum in its polarisation. The electrons would pick up some net spin at first, but that net spin polarisation could well dissipate in transverse phonons or a similar carrier. I'm not sure about the specifics so this might not answer your question, but this mechanism would depend on the electron-transverse phonon coupling in the antenna material.

Comment: Yes, I beleive spin relaxation is short in non-FMs. What about free charges? I am wondering about the fundamental mechanism of how spin is transferred from a bunch of free charges at the transmitting end to the same at the receiving end. (via radiation of course)

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking, but the relevant changes in quantum numbers would be: transmitter electron emits photon (electron ms = +1/2 --> -1/2, photon has ms = +1), receiver electron absorbs photon (electron ms = -1/2 --> +1/2). The rates of emission and absorption will depend on DOS in the transmitter and receiver materials.

Comment: In a normal system half of the electrons in the transmitter have ms = 1/2 and -1/2 for the other half. So half of the EM radiation will have ms +1 and the other half -1. The ms = -1/2 electrons in the receiver absorb the ms = +1 photon and ms = 1/2 electrons absorb -1 photons.

Comment: Now if the transmitter has all electrons with ms = 1/2 then all photons emitted will have ms = -1. But the receiver electrons are not polarized (half of them with ms = 1/2 and other half ms = -1/2) So ms = 1/2 electrons in the receiver absorb ms = -1 photons to become ms = -1/2. But the other half (ms = -1/2) will absorb ms = -1 photon to become ms = -3/2 electrons. To conserve angular momentum. Since this logic seems to be flawed, I want to know what the correct logic is? How does the NET spin in the transmitter get imparted in the receiver.

Comment: The $m_s = -1/2$ electrons just wouldn't absorb those photons. Conservation of angular momentum forces a selection rule there.

Comment: that's what I was wondering. So if the ms = -1/2 electrons don't absorb ms = -1 photons, do these photons just pass through the receiver material? This implies that , on the fundamental level, spin polarization of the transmitter electrons DOES get imparted on the receiver electrons at the cost of cutting the receiver absorption efficiency by half. If this reasoning is correct, my question is answered.

Comment: the antennae model here is a group of free electrons. So these would naturally interact/entangle with each other and constitute a many-body system. So photon absorption/emission needs to be treated collectively. But, as far as I know, many-body effects in a real crystal occur mostly at low temps. So the room temp antenna model here can be subject to 3 approximations: 1)free electrons 2)initial KEs of electrons are  incremental in adherence to exclusion prpl 3)many-body effects can be ignored. So absorption/emission can be treated one on one with the photon. Pl let me know if somethings a miss.

Comment: I was wrong.I think it is more complicated then that. electron is an elementary particle with spin +/- 1/2 the photon is one with spin +/-1. Suppose a free electron is hit by the photon and all the momentum is transferred to the electron in the lab, still for momentum conservation in the cms of electron-photon would need a balancing particle, which can only be an infrared photon in the lab. So even free both electron spins will be available. In a bound semi free state, the infrared photon will be off mass shell, but spins are carried by virtual photons.

Comment: so my opinion is that spin information is not transferred, but I cannot speak about collective effects, i.e. if the classical polarization is built up by individual polarized photons or is a meta level on the photon ensemble.

Comment: @LubošMotl  has a good description in his blog on how classical fields emerge from the quantum substrate, and uses the photons as an example http://motls.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-classical-fields-particles-emerge.html . I am not able to extend the discussion to polarizations from spins. I suspect that "it ain't simple" and will involve assumptions about spatial coherence of spin operators.

Comment: What would be a *spin-polarized current*? An iron wire full of spin-oriented electrons? ☺

Answer (score -1):

A relevant study: see the following work;
[**Universal spin-momentum locking of evanescent waves**](http://arxiv.org/abs/1504.06361) by
Machelan T.V. and Jacob Z.; Univ. of Alberta, Canada And Purdue Univ.

From the abstract:

> We  show  the  existence  of  an  inherent  property  of  evanescent  electromagnetic  waves:
>    spin-momentum locking, where the direction of momentum fundamentally locks the polarization of the wave.  We trace the ultimate origin of this phenomenon to complex dispersion and causality require-ments on evanescent waves.

From the introduction:

> An  important  signature  of  the  recently  discovered  quantum  spin  hall   state  of  matter  is  the  existence  of
>   electronic  surface  states  which  are  robust  to  disorder (non-magnetic  impurities) . *This  property  arises  since  the spin of the electron is intrinsically locked to the direction of propagation (momentum) and the electrons cannot  back  scatter unless there is a spin-flip.* [emphasis mine] Intriguingly, recent experiments have explored an analogous phenomenon in photonics showing polarization dependent directional propagation of optical modes in spontaneously emitted as well as scattered light. For example, experiments have shown that spontaneous emission from atomic transitions is preferentially uni-directed along a fiber depending on the **magnetic quantum number** of the excited state. On the other hand, surface plasmon polaritons excited with circularly polarized light have also demonstrated unidirectional propagation. [...]
>
> A quantum field theoretic treatment has also recently shed light on the interesting spin properties of evanescent waves.[...]
>   In analogy with the behavior of electrons in the quantum spin hall effect,  we call this phenomenon "spin-momentum locking".

Comment: Once more, you just copied the content of the link you give at the end without any personal effort to answer the question. That's not an answer.

Comment: When one is referring to a very narrow area work  its difficult to interject but the info was useful therefore i presented it otherwise i could have given the reference in comment section. if you advise i c an do the same-give the link in comment section.